# how to transfer data in multiple test case in Soap UI (open source)

Tags: soapui

In Log In request two tags (Email and Password) are present.

[image: Screenshot]

I want to use this request Email value in another Test Case (Email Validation) test step.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the request property from Login and use it in Email Validation using the instructions from the soapUI site: http://www.soapui.org/working-with-soapui/point-and-click-testing/point-and-click-with-xpath.html

In that example they get a value from another test step's response, but you can also choose to get a value from a test step's request.  That's what you want.

Comment: thanks for reply. But here property is transferred in between same  test steps.

Answer (score 0):

It is done by Test Suite "custom Properties" option .

In Test Case assign the custom properties. In another test case use this global properties anywhere.